# GLSL 400 samplerCube binding

Tags: opengl, glsl

My partner and I are working on an OpenGL project that includes a skybox. The skybox works fine on his computer (which has GLSL version 4.5) and everything BUT the skybox works on mine (GLSL 4.0). The compiler complains about a syntax error in this line:

```
layout(binding=0) uniform samplerCube currTexture;
```

and the impression I've gotten is that this syntax is not supported by versions of GLSL earlier than 4.2, is this correct? If so, how do I rewrite this line to be compatible with GLSL 4.0? I keep either seeing repeats of how to do this using the newest version, or much longer pieces of code that I am not sure I fully understand / don't know if it's even doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've gotten is that this syntax is not supported by versions of GLSL earlier than 4.2, is this correct?

Yes. `layout(binding=...)` was intruduced in the [`GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_420pack.txt) extension and is core since GL 4.2.

> If so, how do I rewrite this line to be compatible with GLSL 4.0?

You simply omit the `layout(binding)` qualifier. It is only a shortcut for having to query the uniform location and setting the value via `glUniform1i()` on the client side. However, uniforms are initialized to 0 anyways, so in your case, this will just work as before.